# CATransaction Animation Issue

Tags: swift, xcode, cashapelayer, catransaction

I have a `CAShapeLayer` and trying to animate few properties.  I did use `CABasicAnimation` in the beginning, but since this loops over and over, I need the most officient way to do it.

Folowing code animates properly:

```
    private func animateDidBecomeStraight () {
            CATransaction.flush()
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.2)
                self.myShape.fillColor = UIColor.Red.cgColor
                self.myShape.lineWidth = 1
                self.myShape.strokeColor = UIColorRed.cgColor
            CATransaction.commit()
    }

 private func animateDidBecomeUnStraight () {

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
            self.myShape.fillColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
            self.myShape.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
            self.myShape.lineWidth = 0.1
        CATransaction.commit()

    }
```

Strait and Unstraight gets called in order and never in repetition.

### Issue

First time, the animations work with proper durations.  When Strait called first time and when Unstraight called first time.  After that, they seem to lose animation duration.  Changes seem to be instant.

Comment: So what's the goal? Is it straight-unstraight-straight-unstraight... forever? If so, where are your "loops"? I don't see how you are ever triggering these animations, and certainly not after one another. Also, CABasicAnimation was in fact the right way to do this, so please show _that_ code.

Answer (score 1):

CATransaction is not how to do this. Create two CABasicAnimation objects, one for straight and one for unstraight. Join them together in a CAAnimationGroup. Now configure the CAAnimationGroup as repeating.